# Change background color with nth child selector

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I tried using nth child selector but it did not work. maybe the way I wrong or something

```
<ul>
<li class="media list-news">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-10">
            <div>
                <a href="#view/detail-berita.html?id= value.id " class="btn_username_find username_find news-title"> value.title </a>
                <a href="#view/detail-berita.html" class="btn_username_find venueId hide"> value.id </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="description-news"> value.description
                    <span class="link-date-news"> <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>  value.publishDate </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 child-selector">
            <div class="link-source btn-xs btn-source" href="javascript:void(0);">
                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> value.portalName
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/03koh1w4/

Comment: What CSS have you tried, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What exactly you want to happen?

Comment: The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child **of its parent**.

Comment: the code you've given here and the code in jsfiddle is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a few changes (HTML and CSS)

**HTML ->** Don´t close your order list on all item

**CSS ->** Give your (odd and even) to your list, and then to your class

**CSS**

```
.link-source {
  display:inline;
  color:#fff;
}

li:nth-child(odd) .link-source {
    background: green;
}

li:nth-child(even) .link-source {
    background: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="media list-news">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-10">
        <div>
          <a href="#view/detail-berita.html?id= value.id " class="btn_username_find username_find news-title"> value.title </a>
          <a href="#view/detail-berita.html" class="btn_username_find venueId hide"> value.id </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="description-news"> value.description
            <span class="link-date-news"> <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>  value.publishDate </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 child-selector">
        <div class="link-source btn-xs btn-source" href="javascript:void(0);">
          <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> value.portalName
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="media list-news">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-10">
        <div>
          <a href="#view/detail-berita.html?id= value.id " class="btn_username_find username_find news-title"> value.title </a>
          <a href="#view/detail-berita.html" class="btn_username_find venueId hide"> value.id </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="description-news"> value.description
            <span class="link-date-news"> <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>  value.publishDate </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 child-selector">
        <div class="link-source btn-xs btn-source" href="javascript:void(0);">
          <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> value.portalName
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="media list-news">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-10">
        <div>
          <a href="#view/detail-berita.html?id= value.id " class="btn_username_find username_find news-title"> value.title </a>
          <a href="#view/detail-berita.html" class="btn_username_find venueId hide"> value.id </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="description-news"> value.description
            <span class="link-date-news"> <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>  value.publishDate </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 child-selector">
        <div class="link-source btn-xs btn-source" href="javascript:void(0);">
          <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> value.portalName
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="media list-news">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-10">
        <div>
          <a href="#view/detail-berita.html?id= value.id " class="btn_username_find username_find news-title"> value.title </a>
          <a href="#view/detail-berita.html" class="btn_username_find venueId hide"> value.id </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="description-news"> value.description
            <span class="link-date-news"> <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>  value.publishDate </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 child-selector">
        <div class="link-source btn-xs btn-source" href="javascript:void(0);">
          <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> value.portalName
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/03koh1w4/3/)**

Comment: it's work... thanks alot for your help 
i have change my html css

Comment: I would like to ask, if it could be if I add more than 2 colors (green, red) for more colors (green, red, blue, black) and more color ..
thanks